# Spring Test : Rollback the database after testing the dao

Tags: java, spring

I'm looking all the internet i have test many things but i can't find an answer that work on my code.

I would like to RollBack my database after running the tests (or after each test i doesn't really care)

For the moment here is my code :

```
@Transactional
public class ApplicationServiceTest {

    private ApplicationService applicationService;

    @Test
    public void testAddApplication() throws ExceptionMessage
    {
        Application application = applicationService.addApplication("nom", true, "domaineFonctionnel");

        // [...] testing    
    }

    //[...] @Before and @After doing things
}

public class ApplicationService{

    private ApplicationDao applicationDao;

    public Application addApplication(String nom, boolean autorise, String domaineFonctionnel)
    {
        Application application = new Application();

        // [..] Initialise application with parameters

        applicationDao.addApplication(application);     
        return application;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDao extends Dao
{

    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public void updateApplication(Application application) {

        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.merge(application); 
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

So from what I've read the @Transactional should rollback by default my transactions. But it doesn't. Why?

(I have tried to add @Transactional to dao and service but it doesn't change anything)

Comment: you can only rollback whatever you did inside a transaction, as long as you **don't** commit the transaction. once you call`entityManager.getTransaction().commit();` its too late to roll back. and @Transactional does not rollback your transactions. read the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html

Comment: Ok, so what would be the best method to test my fonction ? Without keeping everithing on my database ?

Comment: `@Transactional` will only trigger if you have a fail on your code. The point is, you shouldn't use your actual database in tests, and use some dataset, by example (and use some tool like Jailer to generate some), so you could run real tests and not use your database

Comment: I recommend not rolling back changes made by a test. This ensures that any pending flushes will be performed which would not happen on a rollback. Thus you don't really know if everything worked. If you use an in-memory database which you create for each test (very cheap), you shouldn't have any trouble.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` runner in your test class, the `@Transactional` annotation is ignored.

Try by adding it:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@Transactional
public class ApplicationServiceTest {
```

Answer (score 0):

The davidxxx answer is right. With spring settings this is the standar behaviour.

The official Documentation to read:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-tx-rollback-and-commit-behavior